# Download from AWS S3 to Internet / Data Transfer Out to Internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

SAP is well known for charging for data that moves out of their SAP environment to elsewhere.

Whilst I can understand that download, moving a file from an S3 bucket to my local computer is charged for, my question is then as follows:

- if I run a Spark App to read S3 data, and then use a driver to write to SAP Hana from EC2 from that Spark App, does AWS count and know that this is S3 data being transferred outside the AWS domain to another Cloud?

  - It's a bit different to the foto download from S3 bucket example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that the transfer from S3 to EC2 in the same region is free, but the transfer from EC2 out of AWS has a scaling data transfer fee.

Check out this visual to answer your data transfer pricing questions.  https://github.com/open-guides/og-aws#aws-data-transfer-costs

Comment: Answer is not clear enough. First up I read that but gave the express path via Spark on EMR is EC2. You are saying S3 not relevant but they catch you anyway?

Comment: he's saying: amazon make sure they bill you for every byte moved. Even between EC2 VMs in different availability zones in the same AWS region. Sometimes it costs less to upload to S3 in AZ1 and download in AZ2 than it does to directly share it.